# How to make search more effective in laravel scout and elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-8, algolia, elasticsearch-5, laravel-scout

For the experiment, I am using both algolia and elastic search I see that algolia is searching nicely even  if spellings are wrong but elastic search is searching only if word spelling is complete and correct. How I can make elastic search more effective?

*Algolia*
[image]

*Elastic*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at Fuzzy Query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html